# Add a UIView to SCNScene

Tags: uiview, scenekit

Is it possible to add a UIView to a SceneKit SCNScene?

I have a need where I want a collectionview in the mid ground with some SCNNodes in front and behind.

I can get it working with a hack by screen-shotting the collectionview every-frame and then rendering this as a texture on a node, but it's very slow.

Any other ways around it?

Answer (score 0):

No the is no standard way to bring a uiview in mid of scnnodes. 
Try to stack a skscene to diffuse contents in your scnnode. 
After that bring a uiview to the skscene.